# Lucene: null value when adding a field with DocValues

Tags: java, lucene

I changed a document field to become sortable by search, but now `addDocument()` throws an exception saying that the field value is null, although I verified that email is a non-null string when I add the field. Before the exception Lucene code is getting the `binaryValue()` from the field. It is suspicious that the `StringField` constructor does not accept a custom FieldType. Can I use String fields for sorting? How to fix this?

Lucene 5.3.1

```
    private static final FieldType EMAIL_FIELD_TYPE = new FieldType(StringField.TYPE_STORED);
    static
    {
        EMAIL_FIELD_TYPE.setDocValuesType(DocValuesType.SORTED);
        EMAIL_FIELD_TYPE.freeze();
    }

    ...
        doc.add(new Field("email", email, EMAIL_FIELD_TYPE));
    ...
        writer.addDocument(doc);
        writer.commit();

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field "email": null value not allowed
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SortedDocValuesWriter.addValue(SortedDocValuesWriter.java:65)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.indexDocValue(DefaultIndexingChain.java:435)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:376)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:300)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:234)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:450)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1475)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1254)
```

EDIT:

this code is used for searching:

```
Query q = new WildcardQuery(new Term("email", "*"));
Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("email", SortField.Type.STRING));
TopDocs res = searcher.search(q, Integer.MAX_VALUE, sort);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to separately add a [`SortedDocValuesField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/SortedDocValuesField.html) to take advantage of the new faster sorting in Lucene 5.  When indexing, add the `email` field to your document as follows:

```
doc.add(new StringField("email", email, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new SortedDocValuesField("email", new BytesRef(email)));
```

Also, if you're trying to find all of the documents with emails in your search, it would be better to use a [`new FieldValueQuery("email")`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldValueQuery.html) instead of a `WildcardQuery`.